# How .launch file uses "onInit" and "subscribe" of class(nodelet) in pcl_ros

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, pcl, nodelet, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have gone through the pcl_ros source code and understand all things how it is using PCL. I have cleared understanding regarding the pcl_ros - PCL but not understand how .launch file using its "oninit" and "subscribe" functions in nodelet without calling it (or without any specific main/application file).

For example, In the sample_voxel_grid.launch file mentioned that it is using voxel_grid nodelet but not understand, how it is operating the nodelet.

Anyone can please describe how .launch uses "onInit" and "Subscribe" of nodelet?

Edit:

Hi @Delb

Example:
If you see  [filter.cpp](https://github.com/strawlab/perception_pcl/blob/master/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp) in pcl_ros, you will find the following functions.

```
void pcl_ros::Filter::computePublish (const PointCloud2::ConstPtr &input, const IndicesPtr &indices) 
void pcl_ros::Filter::subscribe()
void pcl_ros::Filter::unsubscribe()
void pcl_ros::Filter::onInit ()
void pcl_ros::Filter::config_callback (pcl_ros::FilterConfig &config, uint32_t level)
void pcl_ros::Filter::input_indices_callback (const PointCloud2::ConstPtr &cloud, const PointIndicesConstPtr &indices)
```

Flow is like
onInit -> config_callback and

subscribe -> input_indices_callback -> computePublish.

So, when call subscribe, it will operate other operations. My question is onit is load by nodelet manager (via .launch file) but here I can see subscribe also operated when I run .launch file. How subscribe function called by nodelet manager/.launch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312743/how-.launch-file-uses-%22oninit%22-and-%22subscribe%22-of-class(nodelet)-in-pcl_ros/) by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2019-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [nodelet wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet#Nodelet_Base_Class:) :

```
void init (const std::string& name, const ros::M_string& remapping_args, const std::vector<std::string>& my_argv); 
// This method is how a nodelet should be started.  The arguments are what is required from the manager to start the nodelet.  This will initialize the nodelet base class and then call the subclass's onInit() method.
```

In your [launch file](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/melodic-devel/pcl_ros/samples/pcl_ros/filters/sample_voxel_grid.launch) there is :

```
  <node name="voxel_grid"
        pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        args="standalone pcl/VoxelGrid">
    <remap from="~input" to="points" />
    <rosparam subst_value="true">
      filter_field_name: ''
      leaf_size: $(arg leaf_size)
    </rosparam>
</node>
```

This will launch the node `nodelet`, which means running the executable built from [nodelet.cpp](https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/blob/indigo-devel/nodelet/src/nodelet.cpp). In the main of `nodelet.cpp`, the nodelet is loaded using the method `load` of the class `Loader` ([line 305](https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/blob/indigo-devel/nodelet/src/nodelet.cpp#L305)) which will then call the method `init` described above ([line 318](https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/blob/indigo-devel/nodelet/src/loader.cpp#L318)).
You can also go deeper in `nodelet_core.cpp` to see the detail of this `init` function, there is the call of `onInit` [line 134](https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/blob/indigo-devel/nodelet/src/nodelet_class.cpp#L134) and see that the method in the header is only defined like this :

```
virtual void onInit() = 0;
```

This definition allows you to overload the method from a derived class (i.e. your class since it inherits from the class `Nodelet`).
So you have to make sure you have overloaded the function `onInit` to use a nodelet and it will be directly launched from the launch file.

I don't really get what you mean with the subscribe part, but you can create `subscribers` and `publishers` directly in the `onInit` function if that's what you asked.

**EDIT :**

The source file you mentionned ([filter.cpp](https://github.com/strawlab/perception_pcl/blob/master/pcl_ros/include/pcl_ros/filters/filter.h)) doesn't have all the functions you listed, especially `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()`, there is a [filter.cpp](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/melodic-devel/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp#L107) with those functions from the official ros-perception package.
The `subscribe()` function is this :

```
pcl_ros::Filter::subscribe()
{
  // If we're supposed to look for PointIndices (indices)
  if (use_indices_)
  {
    // Subscribe to the input using a filter
    sub_input_filter_.subscribe (*pnh_, "input", max_queue_size_);
    sub_indices_filter_.subscribe (*pnh_, "indices", max_queue_size_);

    if (approximate_sync_)
    {
      sync_input_indices_a_ = boost::make_shared <message_filters::Synchronizer<sync_policies::ApproximateTime<PointCloud2, pcl_msgs::PointIndices> > >(max_queue_size_);
      sync_input_indices_a_->connectInput (sub_input_filter_, sub_indices_filter_);
      sync_input_indices_a_->registerCallback (bind (&Filter::input_indices_callback, this, _1, _2));
    }
    else
    {
      sync_input_indices_e_ = boost::make_shared <message_filters::Synchronizer<sync_policies::ExactTime<PointCloud2, pcl_msgs::PointIndices> > >(max_queue_size_);
      sync_input_indices_e_->connectInput (sub_input_filter_, sub_indices_filter_);
      sync_input_indices_e_->registerCallback (bind (&Filter::input_indices_callback, this, _1, _2));
    }
  }
  else
    // Subscribe in an old fashion to input only (no filters)
    sub_input_ = pnh_->subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("input", max_queue_size_,  bind (&Filter::input_indices_callback, this, _1, pcl_msgs::PointIndicesConstPtr ()));
}
```

You can find all these instructions directly in the `onInit()` function of the [unofficial filter.cpp file line 128](https://github.com/strawlab/perception_pcl/blob/master/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp#L128). Those instructions can also be found in the official package, but slightly different, in [feature.cpp line 89](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/melodic-devel/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/features/feature.cpp#L89), and it's still in the `onInit()` function.

So if you want to use this function you can call it directly from `onInit()` or copy and paste the content directly inside the function.

> My question is onit is load by nodelet manager

No it's not, the nodelet manager allows you to load one or multiple nodelets and when you load a nodelet all the functions previously described are called when calling the constructors of your different classes (especially `onInit()` which will then call the subscribe function or directly execute the same instructions).

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-15**:
+1 for the extensive answer, but to summarise: "launch" does *not* use "onInit" and "Subscribe" from nodelet, as the OP asked :)

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-01-15**:
Oops, you're right i forgot the conclusion !

**Comment by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on 2019-01-15**:
You mean to say roslaunch(.launch) is only initializing nodelet and after that nodelet manager handles the rest of the things, Right?

**Comment by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on 2019-01-15**:
@Delb Another thing, in voxel_grid or other pcl_ros nodelets, there is one function called subscribe (ex. in filter.cpp) which handles other operation. How it will handle by nodelet manager?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-01-15**:
The nodelet manager allows you to **load** your nodelets (in launchfile or with rosrun). When loading a nodelet there is a call to the function onInit() that you have overloaded to do whatever you want (as described previously). The manager handles the link between different nodelets.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-01-15**:
And I still don't get your function subscribe, what is bothering you ? Where is it used ?

**Comment by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on 2019-01-16**:
@Delb I have updated the question regarding subscribe.

**Comment by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on 2019-01-16**:
@Delb OK, Thanks for the prompt reply. I understand the whole things.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-01-16**:
Glad to hear that, can you mark the answer as correct if you have no more interrogations ?